# Setup cron job to ping computer and write result to file

Tags: macos, bash, cron, ping

I'm building an interface to basically list computers on my local network that are 'alive' and more or less have a list of these nodes, and their 'status'.

I've created a file called `farm_ping.sh` located under `/Volumes/raid/farm_scripts/_apps/_scripts/farm_ping.sh`

This file contains the following, which simply pings the IP and writes it's result to a txt file also named by the given IP:

```
HOSTS="192.168.1.110"

# no ping request
COUNT=1

for myHost in $HOSTS
do
  count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
  if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
    # 100% failed     
    echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)" > /Volumes/raid/farm_script/nodes_response/$myHost.txt
  else
    # 100% Passed
    echo "Host : $myHost is running (ping successful) at $(date)" > /Volumes/raid/farm_script/nodes_response/$myHost.txt
  fi
done
```

I want this to run this script every minute, here's what I have done to create a cron job:

`env EDITOR=nano crontab -e`

And in the cron job I wrote:

`1 * * * * /Volumes/raid/farm_script/_apps/_scripts/farm_ping.sh`

I saved this file, but it's been 30 mintues, and nothing has written yet, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Try `/bin/bash /Volumes/raid/farm_script/_apps/_scripts/farm_ping.sh` in your crontab. Also make sure your script is executable. Also, you should quote variables.

Comment: Thankyou @BroSlow, if I just run `chmod +x farm_ping.sh`, is that the only thing I'd have to do to make it executable?

Comment: Assuming you are running as yourself when you did `crontab -e`, yes.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working @BroSlow, is this because I may have an error in my script? If I am to update my .sh script, do I have to make it executable again?

Comment: No, it will stay executable. What happens if you run it outside of the cronjob?

Comment: I had just run it and it worked fine, it wrote the file, and I just tested two ips, one which I know is down and the other is working, and it worked great! but the cron job isn't actually running @BroSlow

Comment: Woops, looking at your script, completely ignored your actual cron syntax, this will run on the first minute of every hour. To run every minute, replace the `1` with a `*`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help in the end, even if spent some time chasing herrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was cronjob syntax.

```
1 * * * *
```

In context, `*` means every possible value and a number means a particular time. So this literary means the 1st minute of every hour of every day of every month of every week day.

Replacing the the 1 with a `*` makes it run every minute.